# Python 3 get value from JSON giving error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating json in python3 like this...

```
parsed = json.loads(response.text)
print (json.dumps(parsed, sort_keys=True, indent=2))
```

This gives me...

```
[
    {
        "sample1" : 12,
        "sample2" : 45,
        "sample3" : 45
    },
    {
        "testdata": {
            "testdata1": 45,
            "testdata2": 45,
            "testdata3": 45,
    }
]
```

I am trying to set variables of the data like this....

```
myvalue    = parsed["testdata"]["testdata1"]
print(myvalue)
```

But this is giving me the following error..

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Should be `parsed[1]["testdata"]["testdata1"]`.

Comment: `parsed` is a list. Lists can't be indexed with strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `JSON` starts as a **list**. It's `[object0, object1]`, therefore you can't use `parser['testdata']` **yet**. First, you should access the object you want from the list, thus use `parsed[1]`. Then you can normally access the value you want and the code should look like this `myvalue = parsed[1]['testdata']['testdata1']`.

If you can change the JSON because you're the one creating it, you may want to replace the list with object:

```
{
    "sample":{
        "sample1" : 12,
        "sample2" : 45,
        "sample3" : 45
    },
    "testdata": {
        "testdata1": 45,
        "testdata2": 45,
        "testdata3": 45,
    }
}
```

I think it might be easier, however, it's only a hint based on the example you've given and may not work. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 3):

Your JSON describes an array of two objects, the second one has a `testdata` property.

You should access `parsed[1]['testdata']['testdata1']`